Why does fail2ban report my auth.log file as removed?
I have logwatch running and I check every morning it's content. I have noticed that my auth.log file is erased after an apt upgrade and reboot.
Here is the fail2ban section of the logwatch after an upgrade and reboot yesterday.
--------------------- fail2ban-messages Begin ------------------------


Informational Messages:
        banTime: 600: 1 Time(s)
        encoding: UTF-8: 1 Time(s)
        findtime: 600: 1 Time(s)
        maxLines: 1: 1 Time(s)
        maxRetry: 5: 1 Time(s)
      --------------------------------------------------: 1 Time(s)
      Connection to database closed.: 1 Time(s)
      Observer start...: 1 Time(s)
      Observer stop ... try to end queue 5 seconds: 1 Time(s)
      Observer stopped, 0 events remaining.: 1 Time(s)
      Removed logfile: '/var/log/auth.log': 1 Time(s)
      Shutdown in progress...: 1 Time(s)
      Starting Fail2ban v0.11.2: 1 Time(s)

Notices:
    [sshd] Flush ticket(s) with iptables-multiport: 1 Time(s)

---------------------- fail2ban-messages End -------------------------

Looking at the auth.log file after reboot, it's doesn't look to be new as it contains entries with time stamps older than the reboot.
Is this normal ? Shouldn't it leave the auth.log and rotate it instead ? This looks suspicious.
My Ubuntu version is 22.04.4 LTS server.

The explanation is given here. Fail2ban is not removing the file, it is removing the monitoring of the file. This logging message is confusing and deserve an upgrade.
